# Expected value and correlation

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, correlation

I have the following table, where the first row are the intervals of $y$ variable and the first column are the intervals of the $x$ variable. After getting 4000 samples, I placed their count into the table according to the intervals they fell into.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 x\,\&\,y& -20,-10 & -10,0 & 0,10 & 10,20\\ \hline
 -20,10& 0&0 &0 &500\\ \hline
 -10,0& 0 & 0& 1500&0\\ \hline
 0,10&  0&1500 &0 &0\\ \hline
 10,20& 500 & 0&0 &0\\ \hline
\end{array}

We were supposed to calculate the correlation coefficient for this.

We were given the integral $$R[n_1,n_2]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty x_1x_2p(x_1,x_2,n_1,n_2)\text{d}x_1\text{d}x_2,$$ which I believe does not make any sense (I was unable to find ANY information about it online).
All I see in this equation is the expected value for the product of the two random variables. The result is -75, which again does not make sense to me, as from the table, it would seem that the expected value would be in the middle (which is $0\times 0=0$).

In my probability class, we calculated the correlation coefficient as $$r_s=\rho_{R(X),R(Y)}=\frac{\text{cov}(R(X),R(Y))}{\sigma_{R(X)}\sigma_{R(Y)}},$$ and I have a hard time trying to connect these two equations. I will appreciate any push in the right direction.

My questions are:
Why isn't the expected value 0, as the probabilities are symmetric around zero?
What is the connection between the double integral and the correlation coefficient formula below it?

Thank you.

Comment: What are $n1,n2$ ?

Comment: @Thomas I think they are the numbers of realizations. I am unsure.

Comment: Could you write the table out more clearly? What does an entry in row (10,20) and col  (-20,-10) signify, for instance?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio The following could be an interpretation of my table.

We asked 4000 people to pick a number between -20 and 20 in the morning (x axis intervals), and then we asked the same 4000 people to pick a number between -20 and 20 in the evening (y axis intervals). As can be seen from the graph,  500 people picked a number between -20 and -10 in the morning and then picked a number between 10 and 20 in the evening. So on can be said for other cells in the table. The question in the exam was to calculate the correlation coefficient for this table. Which I am still unsure as how.